# Most efficient method of importing values into an array in an Excel Add-In

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions, excel-addins

I work on an Excel Add-In that has a ton of UDF functions built in and it also has a massive array that gets loaded automatically when you open Excel.  It loads over 25,000 values into a massive array.  This happens in code where we hard-code these numbers.  This has worked great for years, but the main issue is we frequently need to add new values and the only way to do it is for everyone in the company to be out of Excel while I update.

I would like to move all of these values into a spreadsheet, Access table, or some other option depending on suggestions given, then link to it and load the array when you first open Excel.  However, I'm very concerned that something like this would introduce much longer load times for all of our users.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to get these values loaded into the Excel Add-In and also allow me to add new values without introducing a lot of extra load time?

I realize some people may ask for more detail, but the question has to do with loading numbers.  These are unique numbers which can't be otherwise derived, and all subsequent UDFs built into the Add-In require these numbers to function properly.

Comment: If working with a worksheet, just read the data into a `Variant` array.

Comment: Check this post https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/226296/197645